# Problem installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a Power Mac G5

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Power Mac G5, but everytime I try it looks like this:

[image: picture1]

[Link to full picture on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQArARDY5rpeDZha2lLa3pHMEU/view?usp=sharing)

[image: picture2]

[Link to full picture on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQArARDY5rpNGJnNUxSY2kyazQ/view?usp=sharing)

I've got a DVI-to-HDMI adapter and I'm running a Power Mac G5 2GHz 3.5GB of RAM and 500GB hard drive.

Comment: That's a power mac not a mac pro? Have you installed additional drivers?

Comment: What ISO file (actual file name) are you trying to run? Are you trying actual installation, or running as a "Live CD" (if it has that function, I don't know on a G5)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I happened to install Lubuntu (then converted to Xubuntu) on an iMac G4 a while ago. Basically, that problem can be solved by creating the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` with the following lines:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver "radeon"
EndSection
```

Pay attention to the `Driver` line. The iMac I was working on had an ATI video card, but you might need to tweak the line if yours has a different brand.